# Why does TChart left axis title position depend on title length?

Tags: c++builder, teechart

I use fixed `LabelsSize` and `TitleSize` to keep my TChart LeftAxis at the same position, but the axis title (90° vertical) move around depending on its length. It is clear that the title's X position is calculated from the centre of the 0° (horizontal) string length instead of at a fixed position for the top or bottom  of the 90° text, which is independent of length.

Is there a way around this?

Padding with spaces does not work, presumably because these are stripped before the title is plotted.

Thanks

Comment: Which RAD Studio/C++ Builder and TeeChart versions are you using? There have been some related improvements with most recent versions, for example: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1185. If you provide a test case we can run it with our sources to check whether your problem is fixed or not.

Comment: Do you have a sample project we can test here to check whether the problem is fixed or not?

Comment: Sorry Narcis, I forgot to add that I use TeeChart that comes with C++Buider XE5. The problem is easily checked in design mode by setting the left axis title of any XY plot to 90° and see how it moves around with changes in title length. Change orientation to 0° and see how the movement (properly) follows the title length, as one would want with a horizontal title. The point of a vertical title is obviously that it does not move around with title length. I set LabelsSize to a large enough constant so that label lengths (horizontal labels) would not push title left.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think this is fixed with the latest maintenance release. You can download a fully functional evaluation version at http://www.steema.com/download/vcl. Embarcadero's free update (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29708) won't fix it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!

Answer (score 1):

A solution/workaround to this bug (without ditching the bundled version in favor of the evaluation version) is to set the `AutoSize` property of the title to false, and then set the `Width` and `Height` of the title manually to the height of the text to be displayed.

I am using Delphi XE5, and my code looks like this:

```
lBitMap := TBitMap.Create;
try
  lBitMap.Canvas.Font := Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.Font;
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.Width := lBitMap.Canvas.TextHeight(Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.Caption)+5;
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.Height := lBitMap.Canvas.TextHeight(Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.Caption)+5;
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.AutoSize := false;
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.TextAlignment := taCenter;
finally
  lBitMap.Free;
end;
```

Something analog can probably be done in C++, especially since most of the VCL is the same between Delphi and C++ builder.

EDIT 1: Added `TextAlignment` which should be set to `taCenter` so that the title is centered to the axis
EDIT 2: Used font of the title to get `TextHeight` - useful if you change the default font

Comment: Great! Setting AutoSize to false worked like a charm. My c++ code is as follows: